# Sorting an array in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array in perl that contains about 200 indexes that are for a csv file. It likes like the lines below:

```
46.9234784633993,Springwood Drive,Naples,FL
89.7786182217159,W 8th St,Lakeland,FL
```

I want to sort them by that number before the first comma. I tried using just sort, but sometimes the numbers get into the hundreds and thousands and it just sorts all those in the 1's. Then a numerical sort doesnt like it since they are not numerical entries

I tried this

```
my @sortedDistances = sort{ $a <=> $b }(@completedDistances);
and
my @sortedDistances = sort(@completedDistances);
```

Comment: Then a numerical sort doesn't like it since they are not numerical entries ????

Comment: **Show us what you have tried.**  We can't tell from your description what you have done wrong.  Edit your question to include the failing code.  Then, describe what exactly is not working.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a possible solution, try if it works:

```
open FILE, "<", $ARGV[0] or die $!;
my @sorted =
    map { join ",", @{$_} }
    sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map { [ split /,/ ] } <FILE>;
close FILE;
say join "\n", @sorted;
```

EDIT: changed colon to comma

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. It might be worth noting that using something like `split /,/, $_, 2` (with third argument) is more efficient, as it limits the number of regex matches performed. (Also, chomping and then joining with a newline is hilarious; `print @sorted` should work as well)

Answer (score 4):

The classic [*Schwartzian Transform*](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html), which I think `@sdir` intended to code, would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted =  map $_->[0],
              sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
              map [$_, /([^,]+)/], <>;

print for @sorted;
```

Comment: If the last unsorted csv line doesn't end with `\n` and that line is not the last after the sort, two lines will print together, e.g., "46.9234784633993,Springwood Drive,Naples,FL89.7786182217159,W 8th St,Lakeland,FL".  Perhaps `map {chomp; [$_, /([^,]+)/]} <>;` and then `print join "\n", @sorted;` would help.

Answer (score 1):

normal sort to the rescue

```
sort -t, -n -k1,1 file.cvs
```

-t, means separate at comman

-n or -g numerical sort

-k1,2 use column 1 to 2 see -t

[man sort](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort)

Comment: @sdir: no, but the pure guy mentioned 'sort' him self, and used right it can save you a lot of time writing funny perl oneliners, - and debugging them.

Comment: True that. I definitely would have done it with shell sort, too. But perl is more fun (and I use that 'oneliner' actually alot). No offense itended btw.

Comment: Sorry it would have worked but I need to keep it perl now. I didn't know this needs to be done automatically 35000 times

Answer (score -1):

I would write a sort function to get the first item from each and then do the comparison on the items.  It would be of the form:

```
sub sortStuff($$)
{
  my ($a) = split(',',$_[0]);
  my ($b) = split(',',$_[1]);

  return ( $a <=> $b ) ;
}
```

and then call the subroutine as part of the call to sort:

```
@sortedArray = sort sortStuff @array;
```

It will sort on the number and ignore the rest of the items on the line.